# Range Slider or Multi Thumb Slider for SWING

Tags: swing, slider, range, jslider

I need a Multi Thumb Slider for Java. I would need a MultiThumb that can represent a range (so with 2 thumbs) but until now, I can't find any starting point. It must be:

1. consistent with the Nimbus look & Feel
2. usable (pluggable) in Netbeans

Until now I have read all the questions about it but I found that they all refer about `JXMultiThumbSlider` (the web site is down and I can't find a source code for this!) or about `RangeSlider` Jade commons Layer (I don't want to pay for use only 1 component).

Can you help me? all the Sun pages are down since the Oracle acquisition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used this component, called [RangeSlider](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/) : does all I needed. However it is not very customizable in Look&Feel, but maybe this is my fault (I should study more this argoument).

Comment: this RangeSlider is not the one of the Jade commons layer that I cited in the question.